# How can I remove the selected item from the DataGrid? Without using design patterns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, entity

I'm a student, I'm writing a simple application using EntityFrameWork technology.

The other day I ran into such a problem that I cannot delete the selected item from the DataGrid and, accordingly, from the DBMS in my case (MSSQL).

Until that day, always deleting was done this way:

```
    private void deleteStudentsButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DGridStudents.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите запись");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            
        }
        var studentsForDelete = DGridStudents.SelectedItems.Cast<Users>().ToList();
        if (MessageBox.Show($"You definitely want to remove the following items {studentsForDelete.Count()}?", "Wrong!", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                studentsDBEntities.GetContext().Users.RemoveRange(studentsForDelete);
                studentsDBEntities.GetContext().SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Data deleted successfully");
                DGridStudents.ItemsSource = studentsDBEntities.GetContext().Users.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

because before, I deleted a record from the DataGrid, which was filled with only one table.

This time, I needed to fill the DataGrid with two tables, as follows:

```
        using(var db = new studentsDBEntities())
        {
                var q = from Users in db.Users
                        from Groups in db.Groups
                        where Users.roleId == 1 && Groups.id == Users.groupId
                select new
                {
                    Users.id,
                    Users.firstName,
                    Users.lastName,
                    Users.midName,
                    Groups.name,
                    Users.email,
                    Users.password,
                    Users.sex
                };
        DGridStudents.ItemsSource = q.ToList();
       }
```

Until that day, I filled it with a full list of fields from the table as follows and everything worked fine (I'm talking about deleting selected elements)

```
DGridStudents.ItemsSource = studentsDBEntities.GetContext().Users.ToList();
```

At this stage, when trying to remove, I get the following error, because I have been in development not so long ago, I looked for many solutions before writing here, in 90% of cases I came across design patterns like MVVM, that is, I need to create a ViewModel and redo the whole project, I would not want to do this, at least at the development stage of this project, so I decided to ask a question here, can anyone tell me how to solve this problem without resorting to ViewModel.

The error looks like this when trying to delete the selected item:

```
System.InvalidCastException: "Could not cast object type" <> f__AnonymousType1`8 [System.Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String] " to type "WpfApp1.Model.Users". "
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new property to your User class in db context :

```
[NotMapped]
public string groupName {get; set;}
```

or if you are using fluent api you can add this line to your dbcontext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().Ignore(c => c.groupName);
```

and use this query to fill gridview:

```
var q = (from user in db.Set<Users>()
        join group in db.Set<Groups>() on user.groupId equals group.id
        where user.roleId == 1 
         select new Users
                {
                  id=  user.id,
                  firstName = user.firstName,
                   lastName= user.lastName,
                   midName=  user.midName,
                   groupName= group.name,
                   email= user.email,
                   password= user.password,
                   sex= user.sex
                }).ToList();

DGridStudents.ItemsSource = q;
```

Comment: I did everything according to your recommendation, now when I open the window where this request was displayed for me, I get an error: "Entity type or complex type cannot be constructed in LINQ to Entities query"

Comment: @roxyashechka try to replace "new User  {"    with "new {"

Comment: after replace, take this erorr: "System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "<>f__AnonymousType1`8[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]" к типу "WpfApp1.Model.Users"."" before open datagrid

Comment: Could you please show your WpfApp1.Model.Users class with the new groupName  property?

Comment: I have not seen your db context and  am very confused with youir names since you name single object wilt a plural name. I think you have to use  "new Users {"  since it seems to me that  you call your single object Users. Usually  people use User  as a name for a single User and Users as a  name for a list of User.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/roxyash/40589b51af54ea8d900eec075f770cf3
WpfApp1.Model.Users class

Comment: Thank you. Check my answer again. I made some updates.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where I need to include this line?
Which you completed in your answer: modelBuilder.Entity <Users> () .Ignore (c => c.groupName);

Comment: For groupName you have to use [NotMapped] attribute or if you use fluen api you will have to add ignore this property. I need to see your studentsDBEntities if you don't know where to  put the line.

Comment: sudentsDBEntities: https://gist.github.com/roxyash/1caddebcdc4ef471a4653440a4bb7f01

Comment: Ok you are using very old EF. Try just to use new Users { , and let me know what is going on.

Comment: Can we go to telegram? Didn't quite understand what I need to do TG: porettomarco

Comment: I am sorry I don't have any messengers at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228430/discussion-between-sergey-and-roxyashechka).

Answer (score 0):

You could store a reference to the original `Users` object in the anonymous object. Something like this:

```
using (var db = new studentsDBEntities())
{
    var q = from Users in db.Users
            from Groups in db.Groups
            where Users.roleId == 1 && Groups.id == Users.groupId
            select new
            {
                Users.id,
                Users.firstName,
                Users.lastName,
                Users.midName,
                Groups.name,
                Users.email,
                Users.password,
                Users.sex,
                User = Users //< --
            };
    DGridStudents.ItemsSource = q.ToList();
}
```

And to delete:

```
var studentsForDelete = DGridStudents.SelectedItems.Cast<dynamic>().Select(x => (Users)x.User);
```

Comment: After your recommendation, when I try to delete, I get an exception, in the exception handler: Failed to delete object because it was not found in ObjectStateManager

Comment: Did you change your `deleteStudentsButton` implementation then? Are you still calling `studentsDBEntities.GetContext().Users.RemoveRange(studentsForDelete)`?

Comment: Yes I changed what you provided in the answer.

Comment: @roxyashechka: So how did you select the items when it worked?

Comment: like this:var studentsForDelete = DGridStudents.SelectedItems.Cast <Users> () .ToList ();

Comment: Then you get  a `List<Users>`, which you will also get if you call `ToList()` on my suggested enumerable: `var studentsForDelete = DGridStudents.SelectedItems.Cast<dynamic>().Select(x => (Users)x.User).ToList();` No difference as far as the types are concerned. Did you use the same context before or what else has changed?

Comment: seem to understand what the problem is, the fact is that when we delete an element from the date grid in my case, the Users table in the DBMS does not contain the GROUP_ID field with the string type, and when we delete it, we delete the string, because we added the group name instead of id and displayed the same name.
I really don't know how to fix this problem.

ERROS NOW: 
"" <> f__AnonymousType1 <int, string, string, string, string, string> "does not contain a definition for" User ""

Comment: @roxyashechka: Then you didn't add `User = Users` to the `select` as I suggested, did you?